# JQuery or Any other Java Script Lib. for Developing Web application

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

Recently i completed on mid level web application where i have used telerik controls, 
all the developers in project used native javascript functions as well as telerik 
functions to work with javascript.

We faced so many cross browser issues in this approach, we have solved all the issues but i am just wondering that what should be the best approach ?

Do i need to consider JQuery for the next project for avoiding cross browser issues or there is any other option

I want my application should work perfectly in (IE 6+, FF 2+ & Chrome)

Please suggest the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing trivial amounts of JS, then a framework is usually going to be more bandwidth than it is worth. (It doesn't sound like you are, but I think it is important to get that statement out of the way first).

Once you get into serious amounts of JavaScript, then it is worth looking at the various frameworks out there.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is popular. I prefer [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/). I've heard good reports about [ExtJS](http://extjs.com/) for projects described as "web applications". There are a number of other popular [choices](http://www.javascriptlibraries.com/).

It is worth evaluating which best suits the sort of projects you are working on.

Comment: You can avoid the bandwidth issues of including one of the popular JS frameworks by simplying using a CDN provided free of charge: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/

Comment: I was refering to the "The user must make an extra HTTP request and download 16k" (to take jQuery as an example) rather then the costs to the author. 16k of **blocking** data transfer can be quite significant. Especially with the rise of mobile Internet access.

Comment: Another point of using the link above is that many users will already have the js library cached on their browser.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using jQuery. It helped me lot to develop rich applications without writing code that target each and every browser.

Also I found their ***documentation to be relatively simple*** and have a ***large user base*** which is quite an advantage for a library. Also there are ***plenty of plug ins*** that are built on top of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Most people here will suggest you use jQuery. I would suggest you sketch out your requirements and priorities before starting development on your next project and evaluating libraries based on your list of requirements. Using any large general purpose library such as jQuery or Prototype will have implications (download size/delay for user, code quality, trade-offs between generality and speed) you should be aware of before using them.

Comment: No, they won't. There are a lot of StackOverflow users who will, but the feeling is not universal.

Comment: Very true, JQuery is a fan favorite no doubt, but there are a small percentage of us who like other libraries like YUI, prototype, scriptaculous etc.

Comment: Downvote deserved. My answer was hasty, cynical and poor. It's now improved.

Answer (score 0):

I used telerik controls in the past, and I have to say that they are quite a pain in the butt.  They are very rigid and don't allow you any control.  I have found that YUI provides you with a solid javascript framework that has all the features telerik offers, but with non of the limitations.

Check it out [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

Comment: If i continue to use telerik controls(as i am having license) then also this YUI library will supoort

Answer (score 0):

as most have already posted, it all depends on what you need to do, i used jQuery, script.aculo.us, and Mootools for some time, and for lightweight effects mootools was the most appropriate, as for support and medium sized projects jQuery. script.aculo.us is pretty usefull as it is based on prototype, but it took me some time to figure out how to actually use it effectively

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer JQuery and ASP.NET AJAX (Microsoft AJAX Library). There are so many JQuery Plug-in available which you can try them out. As for ASP.NET platform, Microsoft AJAX Library is inevitable because of its simplicity and tight integration with ASP.NET controls. Recently, JQuery has attained citizenship in Visual Studio 2008. This should also be taken into account.